# How to load a data fixture with get_by_natural_key() on ContentType foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, json

I'm having trouble loading an external data fixture for a model that uses a `ContentType` foreign key.

I'm using a manager in the models, like the docs say. Unfortunately, although the docs talk about the importance of a `get_by_natural_key` method on a `ContentType` foreign key, it then launches into a different example instead. I'm having trouble figuring out just what the manager would look like. My best guess is to use `get_by_natural_key` again, and assign `app_label` and `model` lookups, but I could be way off.

```
# models.py 
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ 

class InlineTypeManager(models.Manager): 
    def get_by_natural_key(self, title, app_label, model): 
        return self.get(title=title, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app_label=content_type__name, model=content_type__id)) 

class InlineType(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=255) 
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to={"model__in": ("Link", "Document", "Image", "Audio", "Video", "MediaSet", "Flash", "Testimonial")}) 

    objects = InlineTypeManager() 

    class Meta: 
        ordering  = ["title"] 
        verbose_name = _("inline type") 
        verbose_name_plural = _("inline types") 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return u"%s" % (self.title)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

My `initial_data.json`:

```
[
    {
        "model": "inlines.inlinetype",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Image",
            "content_type": "image"
        }
    }, {
        "model": "inlines.inlinetype",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "title": "Video",
            "content_type": "video"
        }
    }
]
```

When I `loaddata` my JSON, I receive the error:

```
DeserializationError: [u"'image' value must be an integer."]
```

The point of `get_by_natural_key` is to load non-integer fields in a "human-friendly" lookup because hard-coded IDs in the JSON is a bad idea because of its unpredictability, so I'm guessing my manager is failing. Or should I use `get_for_model()`/`get_for_models()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

natural key in Django is

> The default serialization strategy for foreign keys and many-to-many relations is to serialize the value of the primary key(s) of the objects in the relation.

You don't need to implement methods such as natural_key and get_by_natural_key in Manager for those models which do not occur as ForeignKey/ManyToManyField in targets to dump. So you could remove InlineTypeManager() lines.

Also, the values of content_type field inside dumped initial_data.json are incorrect. Django only treats a list as natural key, a string like "image" is still treated as surrogate key and will fail because it cannot be coerced to int successfully. Correct ContentType dump looks like

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils import simplejson

>>> simplejson.dumps(ContentType.objects.get(model='user').natural_key())
'["auth", "user"]'
```

Comment: "You don't need to implement methods such as natural_key and get_by_natural_key in Manager for those models which do not occur as ForeignKey/ManyToManyField in targets to dump." I'm confused...how is my model not using a ForeignKey? `InlineType` has `content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)`. And your answer seems to be about dumping. I want to `loaddata` not dump it out, so my JSON may be slightly incorrect, but the answer is not to dump it with `simplejson`.

Comment: @richiec Your dumped JSON is incorrect, such as "content_type": "video" , which fails loaddata. The json should looks like the dump result I showed here, like ["auth". "user"]. I didn't mean not using FK, I mean natural_key and get_by_natural_key methods are only for those models which are pointed to through FK. In you case, ContentType is in FK field of InlineType, thus ContentType need to implement natural_key and get_by_natural_key, which it already has. InlineType, which is the target model you dump to and load from JSON file, does not referenced by FK and hence no need to have the methods

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right! Thank you so much. In my case, my app/model pair would  be ["media", "image"] and ["media", "video"]. It's strange to me that the docs implied a manager would be necessary with ContentType when it's supplied automatically. Thanks again!